# DISQUS: How to handle when user added a comment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, disqus

I need to handle event when user added a comment in Javascript.

Comment: Despite its shortness, it's a valid question. +1

Comment: I need to increment comments count for a story on added a new comment...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this March 2010 conversation](http://groups.google.com/group/disqus-dev/browse_thread/thread/e743753d0cdeb574) with Disqus developers, there is no such event hook at the moment.

I can't find anything newer, so this may still be the current state of the nation.